# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable within for loop Python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to call a method multiple times with the use of a for loop but change the value of a variable (`i`) that will be passed into the method (`method1`) on every iteration. I planned to do this within a for loop but keep getting the error:

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

I have looked at other similar issues but none seem to resolve my issue or provide a way to still call the method in the way I desire.

```
array = np.array([1, 63, 96, 122, 35, 52, 67, 0.01])

for i in array:
    result = method1(collection, data, i)
    method1= price.dot(result)
```

Any help with this would be much appriciated!

Comment: Is `method1` really a function?  Might it be a numpy array (by mistake)?  Or does the error occur inside `method1`?  You might need to show the full error and traceback.

Comment: Yes this was the cause of my error I have expanded the example code to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop when you assign
`method1 = price.dot(result)`
method1 is now a `numpy.ndarray` and on the next iteration of the loop it is not callable anymore

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to loop through numpy array with that. Just wondering you don't have a space between 'method' and '1' in your code, do you? Because there shouldn't be a space there...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was a typo from formatting my question and not in my code, I have now changed it.